# "file" command is not very good at figuring out what my javascript files are

Tags: linux, macos, file, unix

It reports "ASCII C++ program text" or "ASCII English text" for various js files I have. For my node.js app.js it says it is "a node script text executable".

Now these are all correct in that they are all text files, but only the node script is correctly classified. How can I adjust my script to properly detect js files? I can't really think of many reasonable ways to use both the filename and the output of `file` to reason about the actual nature of a file (e.g. what linter to feed it to).

It seems like the only practical approach could be: if `file` tells me any non-ambiguous classification, I go by that, otherwise, I go by the filename extension.

Comment: You've provided a reasonable approach, and unless you're planning on improving file's ability to distinguish different text file formats, it's probably the most practical approach.

Comment: I agree, I would use the same approach.